# Considerations and suggestions for QA lead responsible for software testing and development processes

Tags: automated-testing, agile-testing, agile, qa-role, development-process

I am offered a position as a QA lead, which is a big-big step up for me.

I would appreciate some feedback, heads-up, suggestions, certify and considerations when tackling such a responsibility.

What is expected of the QA lead:

- Implement software testing process from scratch: how to test, what to test, what tools, what responsibility
- Evaluating the development process and suggesting points for improvement
- Creating ecosystem of unit, integration, system, load, penetration and regression test suites and mocks. Which is durable, low maintenance required and scaling up is simple
- Create a process where QA and Dev are closely coupled. Meaning that from test plan to requirements to test cases to actual test results and bug- all are traceable and seamless

Note: Yes, I am definitely under-qualified for the position, but the company is OK if I learn everything along the way, but first results are expected during the first quarter.

Note-Note: Yes, there are similar questions, but since I am responsible both for QA and Dev processes, I asked a separate question.

Comment: Questions on StackExchange should lead answers based on facts, as your current question is worded it is too broad and will lead to mostly opinionated answers. Consider rewriting your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but I would like to answer a bit on one of your notes.

> Note: Yes, I am definitely **under-qualified** for the position, but the
>   company is OK if I learn everything along the way, but first results
>   are expected during the first quarter.

Are you really under-qualified? From your list of tasks it seems you have a clear goal, which sounds perfectly fine to me. 70% of the people have to [overcome the Impostor Syndrome](http://www.forbes.com/sites/margiewarrell/2014/04/03/impostor-syndrome/#3f537031eb9d). You are more perfect for the job than you think you are.

Just take small steps, try to change one thing at a time, until it becomes a routine. Adapt your goals with any information you gain while executing these small steps.

Comment: Thanks! The Impostor Syndrome really opened my eyes. And also probably the main issue was that I could not dissect my issue into small steps.